# How to filter string list in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to filter the string list by other string table.

How to implement blow table?

```html
Raw column    Filter condition  Filtered Result
-----------   -------------     ---------------
ultrasonic     device           ultrasonic
atomizer       with             atomizer
device         unit             ultrasonic
with           pocket-type                 
unit           and           
ultrasonic
unit 
device
pocket-type
and
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using filter like this:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, ISNA(MATCH(A2:A, B2:B,0)))
```